# Google maps API marker changes location of users on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm having an issue with Google maps API.

I have a project which has users array in it. Each user has a location, which is given in the following form: 'country city street'.

In order to mark a user on the map, using Marker, I am creating a new array, coordination array, by  mapping over the user's addresses and using Geocode.fromAddress.

What I am doing is creating coordination array respectively to the users array ( coordinationsArray[0] is the coordination of usersArray[0]'s address).

Now, something very odd is happening, and each time I refresh the page, for some reason my marker is changing. As if, if a certain user was pointed on the map in address X, after refresh it changes, what seems to be arbitrarily, with another user's address.

The following initialization of the map:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "react-google-maps";
import usersAndProductsContext from "./Contexts/usersAndProducts-context";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import { Stack } from "@mui/system";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const googleKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY;

function Map() {
  Geocode.setApiKey(googleKey.toString());
  Geocode.setLanguage("en");
  Geocode.setRegion("il");

  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext);
  let farmersArr = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.filter(
    (user) => user.isFarmer === true
  );
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  let [farmers_coordinations, set_farmers_coordinations] = useState([]);
  let [isClicked_onmap_farmer, set_isClicked_onmap_farmer] = useState(false);
  let [selected_coordinate, set_selected_coordinate] = useState(null);
  let [selected_farmer_id, set_selected_farmer_id] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    farmersArr.map((farmer) =>
      Geocode.fromAddress(farmer.location).then(
        (response) => {
          set_farmers_coordinations((farmers_coordinations) => [
            ...farmers_coordinations,
            response.results[0].geometry.location,
          ]);
          // console.log(response);
          // console.log({farmers_coordinations})
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      )
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({farmers_coordinations}) + JSON.stringify({farmersArr}))
  }, [farmers_coordinations])


  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: 32.0853, lng: 34.7818 }}>
      {farmersArr.map((farmer, i) => (
        <Marker
          key={farmer.id}
          position={farmers_coordinations[i]}
          onClick={(e) => {
            set_isClicked_onmap_farmer(true);
            set_selected_coordinate(e.latLng);
            set_selected_farmer_id(farmer.id);
            let res = farmersArr.find(
              (farmer) => farmer.id === selected_farmer_id
            );
            // set_current_clicked_farmer(res)
          }}
          icon={{
            url: "/pointer-map.svg",
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25),
          }}
        />
      ))}
      {isClicked_onmap_farmer && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={selected_coordinate}
          onCloseClick={() => {
            set_selected_coordinate(null);
            set_isClicked_onmap_farmer(false);
            set_selected_farmer_id(null);
          }}
        >
        
          <Stack
            direction="column"
            flexWrap="wrap"
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: "gray",
              borderRadius: "10px",
              cursor: "pointer",
            }}
            onClick={() => navigate(`/farmershop/${selected_farmer_id}`)}
          >
            <h1
              style={{
                alignSelf: "center",
                fontFamily: "Amatic SC",
                fontWeight: 700,
                fontSize: "30px",
                color: "white",
              }}
            >
              {
                farmersArr.find((farmer) => farmer.id === selected_farmer_id)
                  .firstname
              }{" "}
              &nbsp;
            </h1>
            <h1 style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontFamily: "Amatic SC" }}>
              {" "}
              {
                farmersArr.find((farmer) => farmer.id === selected_farmer_id)
                  .lastname
              }
            </h1>
            <Stack>
              <img
                alt="Error loading"
                style={{
                  maxWidth: "70%",
                  alignSelf: "center",
                  borderRadius: "30px",
                }}
                src={
                  farmersArr.find((farmer) => farmer.id === selected_farmer_id)
                    .img
                }
              />
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

function FarmersMap() {
  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "27vw",
        height: "100vh",
        marginTop: "5vh",
        borderRadius: "30px",
      }}
    >
      <h1
        style={{
          letterSpacing: "2px",
          color: "lightgray",
          fontFamily: "Amatic SC",
        }}
      >
        search for your iFarmer
      </h1>
      <WrappedMap
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }}></div>}
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${googleKey.toString()}`} // NEED TO PUT IN .ENV THE KEY
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }}></div>}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: " 100% " }}></div>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default FarmersMap;
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Regards!

Comment: Are there any errors you have encountered?

Comment: Nope. No errors .

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that replicates the issue like a codesandbox so that the community could help you better. I tried the code you provided on a sandbox and I can't seem to make it work. You should provide it yourself by editing the question.